# Log-terminal singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

We know from the Young Person's Guide of Miles Reid that every quotient singularity is log-terminal in 2 dimensional case. Is there a similar result holds in dimensions $\geq$  3. If so, what is the exact reference for this?

Comment: As pointed by Karl: In fact we are looking at quotients by finte cyclic groups.

Comment: By a theorem of Viehweg,  finite quotient singularities on a variety over an algebraically closed field are rational. Is is true that rational singularities are log-terminal?

Comment: Rational singularities are not generally log terminal.  Log terminal singularities are rational.  Perhaps I should point out that there are a number of generalizations to that result you mention, including what's sometimes called Boutot's theorem (one form of which is: a summand of a ring with rational singularities has rational singularities, see further generalizations also by Sandor Kovacs).  

Answer (score 4):

I guess it depends on what groups you are quotienting out by (finite groups, reductive groups?), anyway, for example see

- *The cone of curves on algebraic varieties* by Y. Kawamata, Prop. 1.7 and the following discussion in the finite group case.

For some generalities to non-finite groups, see

- *Pure subrings of regular rings are pseudo-rational* by Hans Schoutens, Theorem B

You can find some discussion I'm sure in other standard sources such as *Flips and Abundance for Algebraic Threefolds* by Koll\'ar et. al.  Also see Kollar-Mori.

Comment: In fact we are looking at quotients by finte cyclic groups.